# acer aspire one keyboard

Tags: keyboard, acer

HELP!
keyboard is messed up after plugging in a desktop keyboard.
example.
"qwerty456*[]
asdfgh123-'\
zxcvbn0,."

cannot write without pressing the Fn key for messed up 2eys!
"he3* 0e *3ease!"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your NumLock is turned on. Have you tried pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> on your laptop keyboard to turn it off?

Comment: LOL! Yes!!OMG! WOW thank you! That is ridiculous! you are amazing thank you! plus one for askubuntu.com